# Cannot use ansible_user with local connection

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook for running on `localhost`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: foo
    - role: bar
    - role: baz
```

Then in various tasks I want to use `ansible_user`, but I get the error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'ansible_user' is undefined"}

Comment: Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

Okay figured it out.

In any task that uses `become: true`, e.g.:

```
- name: foo
  become: true
  file:
    path: /tmp/foo
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ansible_env.USER}}"       # cannot use {{ansible_user}}
    group: "{{ansible_env.USER}}"       # cannot use {{ansible_user}}
    mode: "0755"
```

So instead of `ansible_user`, we must use `ansible_env.USER` or `ansible_env.USERNAME`.

I think this is because ansible doesn't know which user to use - if it's a local connection, and we elevate permissions, then is the "ansible user" actually root, or is it the user running the playbook? Ansible gets confused so the variable is empty... I think.

(For this to work we must have `gather_facts: true` at the beginning of the play.)

Comment: Which version of ansible are you running ? Please see @vladimir's playbook in his answer which works perfectly fine under ansible 2.9.9. `ansible_user` is the user used for connection. It is not `become_user`(root by default) used  for privilege escalation. These are totally distinct users. There is no such thing as ansible not knowing which one to use. This looks like a bug.

Comment: @Zeitounator I'm using 2.9.7. I will try out his code as well to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"Cannot use ansible_user with local connection."*

A: There must be some kind of misconfiguration. The playbook below works as expected and there is no reason it wouldn't work with these tasks inside a role.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "ansible_user [{{ ansible_user }}]"
      become: false
    - file:
        path: /tmp/foo
        state: directory
        owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        group: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      become: false

    - debug:
        msg: "ansible_user [{{ ansible_user }}]"
      become: true
    - file:
        path: /tmp/bar
        state: directory
        owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        group: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      become: true
```

Comment: This playbook works for me with ansible 2.8.6 but it does not work with ansible 2.9.21. I get the same error as @Ionix:
`'ansible_user' is undefined`